# Entity Framework Include without Relations

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I am working on a huge project using Entity Framework. Because I made almost all entities time-dependent it is not possible to use relations between entities anymore (I manage the relations myself).
The problem that came up is that I am not longer able to query data as easily as I could before.
Say I have an entity called `Student`. This entity contains a collection of `Books` (List) which belong to the student. Each book contains an author property which comes from the database as well.
To load all the students with theirs book and the corresponding authors I either have to write hundreds of custom queries (f.e. linq) or I lazy load them which results in a big performance impact. 
Actually it would be great if I could use the Inlude of Entity Framework without relations. Does anybody know how to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If Entity Framework is not managing the relations between the tables, then it has no way of using `.Include()` which would create joins in the SQL call.  Your best option would be to add the related entities to the parent as normal, but use the `[NotMapped]` Attribute.  Then you can use a custom SQL call to perform your lookups and populate the properties when you need them.  I am confused, however, by your statement that because the entities are "time-dependent" that you can't use relationships, which are simply Foreign Keys in the database...  Perhaps there's something else you can do to optimize your entities.  If you are managing your own relationships between items, you are offloading a lot of the responsibility from your DB into your app, which seems like a lot of work already.

**Update**

Implementing an Audit Trail is a fairly standard process in Entity Framework, and probably much easier than managing your relationships.  An audit trail basically involves having an event handler for the `Context_SavingChanges()` method, and then working with your new data and old data through the `ObjectStateManager`.  Adding logic within this loop you could also invalidate or reject additions/updates that don't fall within a specific time frame.

A good example of an Audit Manager is on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34491/Implementing-Audit-Trail-using-Entity-Framework-Pa), where the author demonstrates a method to not only store audit information, but also roll back.

Comment: Thank you Andrew!I decided to remove all the relations because I need all data to stay in the database and an entry can have different values over time. Also the relations between entities can only be valid in a specific time-range.I have no idea how to implement such a system using the Entity Framework relations? Doesn't seem to support such a scenerio.However I think it should be possible to write a custom Include method extension with an additional parameter that defines the relation (to which table (DbSet) the join should be made and which the foreign key is).Any idea how to do this?

Comment: There are methods to Implement an Audit Trail in Entity Framework, and managing the validity of relationships is easy enough... I'll update my answer with some links.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your time! I appreciate it. In the past I used to work with Audit Trail but this time it should be possible to change the entire system's state of being to a particular timepoint within a second. In other words it should be possible to simulate two different points in time simultaneously. Could you please tell me more about the [NotMapped] Attribute? Is it not possible with a fair effort to extend the IQueryable with another method called IncludeNotMappedRelation(this IQueryable, property, relationToDbSet, foreignKey)?

Answer (score -1):

If there is no primary key and foreign key relationships between the entities then you cannot use the Include method.