# EF Ignores Eager-Loading "Include" statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've seen this issue come up [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595511/entity-framework-4-eager-loading-include-with-filters-using-self-tracking-ent) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209600/entity-framework-include-without-relations) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881633/linq-filter-collection-with-ef).  As I read through the answers, the common-ish answer is summarized well by this statement:

> any manual join or projection will change the shape of the query and Include will not be used
>   -[Ladislav Mrnka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3595568/284758)

Ok, so I decided to make a "hello world" sample EF code-first project with DbContext that would test that statement.  I created the following query:

```
var result = 
    from c in context.Customers.Include(i => i.Addresses)
    from a in c.Accounts
    where a.ID > 4
    select c;
```

The Include() statement should work, because I'm clearly meeting the requirements: (1) I am not modifying the projection by using an anonymous type and (2) I am not manually handling the joins.

Nevertheless, it doesn't work.  The SQL query generated by this query is this:

```
SELECT 
  [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
  [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
  FROM  [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Accounts] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[Customer_ID]
  WHERE [Extent2].[ID] > 4
```

If I remove the join and filtering on the `Accounts`, then the include statement is correctly generated.  Why is this happening?

I'm also bothered that EF official documentation doesn't seem to explain the rules of when Include() is or is not honored.  Did I simply overlook something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a way you are "manually handling a join" by specifying the second `from` statement with `c.Accounts`.

Try the below query, whose context is solely based on a `Customer` entity:

```
from c in context.Customers.Include( i => i.Addresses )
where c.Accounts.Any( a => a.ID > 4 )
select c
```